# Ubuntu 18.04.1 turns black randomly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, amd-graphics

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. At random, my screen windows turn black. However, app bar and side bar stay visible. Doing a "ctrl-tab" shows running apps, I can switch apps, but all app windows remain black (see screenshots). They stay black and I can't seem to recover from it other than logging-out and then back in which is super annoying since I lose the work that's on the desktop and I lose a lot of productivity. The "black outs" only happen when I either do a mouse click or switch windows. Black-outs never happen self-spontaneously.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CWpw.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q41CB.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYMIY.jpg

Specs:

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- Graphics card: ATI RV530
- Gnome: 3.28.2
- 64-bit
- CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz × 12
- motherboard: asus

Answer (score 1):

The issue is tracked as a bug of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS under #1799947. I'm experiencing the same thing on a Radeon X1350 (old HP-Compaq laptop). Update of graphics drivers does not solve it, even if proprietary drivers are used.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the bug report, please?